# Relationship query - child that fetches its parent with all its children

Tags: relationships

I have a custom object rstk__poline__c that has a child yo parent relationship to rstk__sylocid__c. The parent object (rstk__sylocid__c) also has a parent to child relationship with rstk__sylocnum__c.

I want to build a query that fetches all the polines (rstk__poline__c) with the their location ids (rstk__sylocid__c) and I want those location ids to also fetch the location numbers (rstk__sylocnum__c) from the parent to child relation ship.

Can you please tell me if I can achieve this in one query? I can't manage to find a solution for this. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

SOQL doesn't allow you to traverse back down in the same query. You would need to break this into two queries.